# The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have error but can't understand or solution it

the error that show : The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable

```
// List used
List<int> Licture_begin = <int>[8, 10, 14];
List<int> periode_Lecture = <int>[2, 3, 1];


Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: periode_Lecture[
                                              Licture_begin.indexOf(i)],
                                          child: Column(children: const [
                                            Text(
                                              "المادة",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "القاعة-اسم الدكتور",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                            )
                                          ]),
                                        ),
                                        for (int j = 0; j < 1;j++)
          / /here the error             i = i + periode_Lecture[Licture_begin.indexOf(i)]
                                      ],
                                    )
```

I am trying to add to last . to `Int()` but it doesn't work

Comment: `children` is supposed to be a `List` of `Widget`s.  Your collection-`for` loop is including a sequence of `int`s in that `List`, and `int`s are not `Widget`s.  What is that loop intended to do?  If you're looping for a side-effect, you should do that separately.

Comment: On top of @jamesdlin's comment, your loop doesn't even necessarily do any looping, as you're initialising "j" at zero, but then telling it to loop only when "J" is less than one ... so the "loop" will essentially happen once ..... therefore no really point to having a loop.  You are clearly trying to achieve some other result that is not - as james pointed out - relevant to the widget "children" of the Row()

Comment: i tried it in function but the fun ction doesn't work , give me advice how to do it or search for thing @jamesdlin

Comment: @BavliBadry I don't understand what your code intends to do, nor do I understand what you tried ("but the function doesn't work" provides no insight), so I can't tell you what you to do.